# javascript convert image to data url

Tags: javascript, todataurl

Using javascript I convert a jpg into data url (I get a string like data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQAB...), the url I get is working as href in Firefox, but it is not working in Chrome.
Do you have any suggestion? Maybe there's a limit in Chrome?

EDIT:

1. I use the data url as href in an anchor with attribute download (link should force an open/download popup)
2. If I pass a smaller image it's working on Chrome

You can see an example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/ex180Lyu/

`<a href="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJR..." download="image.jpg">CLICK</a>`

It's working in Firefox but not in Chrome

Comment: This suggestion may not suit your requirement but setting the img tag src attribute should work in any browser <`img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQS...." />`

Answer (score 1):

Chrome stops supporting data URI s in new window. Here is the issue reported

https://github.com/piskelapp/piskel/issues/729

If your need is testing, you can do like this, which supports any browser

`<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQAB...." />`

Answer (score 1):

Chrome removed the possibility to navigate to data-uris, as Nithin said.

But you'd be fine to set it on any webpage within an `<img>` tag like this:

```html
 <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQAB..." alt="Alt text for image"/>
```

You can also show a download link like this:

```html
<a href="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQAB..." download="image.jpg">image</a>
```

If the image is too big to try this method you can always copy it to a canvas. I've been successful with images up to 20MB.

Basically you copy the image to the canvas directly:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const img = new Image();

img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQAB..."
img.onload = () => {
  canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
  canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
```

Full code [here](https://codepen.io/andion/pen/PoqYZLg)

Comment: Thanks for reply, instead of an img tag I need an anchor with attribute href="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQAB..." and attribute download="image.jpg"

Comment: Yes, if downloading it is what you want to do, that should be the way to go. Glad I helped

Comment: I updated the example and added a codesandbox working example. As @khpa said you could be hitting a size limit. If that's the case you can also try copying and pasting the image on a <canvas />. I was successful doing that even with 20MB images

Comment: Thanks! Then, how do I make a donwload link like <a href="..." download="image.jpg">image</a>?

Comment: You can always programatically re-create a link with the said base64 content (`<a href="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQAB..." />) but if it was too long before I guess it would be too long this time. If you right click the image you'd be able to donwload it though. I'll give it a thought now that you updated the question with an example.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed a limit, have you checked this? :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs#Common_problems

a very good answer is this:

[What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)

Comment: Thanks for replay, do you have any suggestion to workaround (see last edit in main post)?